# How can i update npm without error? (npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function)

Tags: npm, npm-install

I accidently downgraded npm for a project and i cannot upgrade npm back.

node: v16.13.2
npm: 4.6.1

I tried this

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

but it gives me this error

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
```